# QR code generate django-admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

how generate and print the qr code with the data above the button after pressing "Print qr code"?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can convert any string to a QR code image , i used this code snippet long ago in few of my earlier projects.
Though I'm not sure, which Django or Python version you are using, but i hope this will give you a rough idea.

Common use: `<img src="{{object.attribute_to_encode|qr:"120x130"}}" />`

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def qr(value,size="150x150"):
    """
        Usage:
        <img src="{{object.code|qr:"120x130"}}" />
    """
    return "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=%s&cht=qr&chl=%s&choe=UTF-8&chld=H|0" % (size, value)
```